# question related to the krull schmidt theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated projective $R$-module, where $R$ is an Artinian ring. Then I must show that $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of principal indecomposable $R$-modules.

We have a surjective map $\varphi:R^n \to M$ since $M$ is finitely generated, and using the short exact sequence $0 \to \ker \varphi \to R^n \to M \to 0$ we get that $M$ is both Artinian and Noetherian. Hence $M$ has finite length. So by the Krull-Schmidt theorem, we can write $M$ as a direct sum of indecomposable modules. Why are these modules principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A principal indecomposable module is just an indecomposable direct summand of $R$.  As $M$ is finitely generated projective it is a direct summand of some $R^n$.  Krull-Schmidt then gives that any indecomposable summand of $M$ is therefore a summand of $R$; hence principal.